# How do I use zheevd to diagonalize an hermitian matrix?

Tags: matrix, lapack

I am trying to diagonalize an Hermitian matrix using ZHEEVD.
This is the subroutine I use to diagonalize-

```
  SUBROUTINE NAGdiagocc(nsit)
  use NAGmodule

  complex*8,  allocatable :: WORK(:)
  integer, allocatable :: IWORK(:)
  real*8,  allocatable :: RWORK(:)

  CHARACTER JOB, UPLO
  EXTERNAL zheevd
  NMAX=nsit
  LDA = NMAX
  LIWORK = 5*NMAX + 3
  LRWORK = 2*NMAX*NMAX + 5*NMAX+10
  LWORK = NMAX*(NMAX+2)+100

  ALLOCATE(WORK(LWORK),IWORK(LIWORK),RWORK(LRWORK))

  JOB='V'
  UPLO='U'

  CALL ZHEEVD(JOB,UPLO,nsit,gammamat,LDA,evalocc, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, LRWORK, IWORK, LIWORK, INFO )

  IF (INFO.GT.0) THEN
  WRITE (*,*) 'Failure to converge.'
  stop
  endif

  deALLOCATE(WORK,IWORK,RWORK)

  return
  end
```

I try to diagonalize a simple matrix but the eigenvalues I obtain are completely wrong.
And repeating the diagonalization different times with a do loop in the main program I obtain each time slightly different results.
What could be the problem?

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d6/dee/zheev_8f.html) of `ZHEEV` states that `gammamat` and `WORK` should be `complex*16`. Could it explain your problem ? Are you looking for `CHEEVD` [documentation](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/da/d56/cheevd_8f.html) ?

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly this the problem